# Favicon not being displayed

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have pasted the following code in the v4 master page

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server"IconUrl="https://kpitc.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing-Portal/SiteAssets/favicon.ico"/>
```

but still the favicon is not being displayed.

Comment: What code? Is it invisible? :P

Comment: i have pasted the following code in the v4 master page but still the favicon is not being displayed. Please help!<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="https://kpitc.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing-Portal/SiteAssets/favicon.ico"/>

Answer (score 2):

Try the following markup

```
<link rel="shortcut icon apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.ico?rev=28" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" id="favicon1" />
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default *oslo.master* MasterPage, open it in sharepoint designer also and find this line:

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
```

Change this line and should be done.